# Is there a ZSH equivalent to "shopt -s nullglob"?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

I'm currently working on a script that deletes all the PNG files from my Desktop. I want to create an array of file paths then use the `rm` command on each one.

This is the relevant bit of code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

files=("$HOME"/Desktop/*.png)
files_found="${#files[@]}"

shopt -u nullglob
```

It has been recommend that I use `shopt` in case of no matching files.

However I'm on MacOS and just discovered that `shopt` is not available for ZSH. When I run the script I get `command not found: shopt`.

I've found the ZSH has an equivalent called `setopt` however after reading through the [documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html) I can't quite figure out which option is the correct one to use in the case. I can't seem to find any examples either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Since your script starts with `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, when it's being executed as its own process (this does require that it have `+x` permissions) it should _always_ use bash, and not zsh. There's a curious problem to run down if that isn't being honored.

Comment: I thought that as well. It was my understanding that the shebang dictated which interpreter should be used.

I recently installed the newest version of Bash on my Macbook. I'm not sure if that could have caused any issues.

Comment: How are you starting it? `sh yourscript` or `zsh yourscript` or `source yourscript` or `. yourscript` will all ignore the shebang.

Comment: ...btw, adding `echo "Bash version is: $BASH_VERSION"` is a cheap/easy way to see if it is in fact bash in use, and if so which version.

Comment: (also, I may have edited this in after you already saw my first comment, but if the script _isn't executable_, that's another thing that can cause the shebang to be ignored; some shells fall back to treating things that can't be invoked with `execve()` as sh scripts; I don't remember definitively if zsh is one of those, but I vaguely think it is).

Comment: Ahh so I've auto-loaded the function into my .zshrc. Think that's what's caused it!

Just run the script with Bash and it's worked fine!

Thanks again! That's two nights in a row you've helped me out now :)

Comment: Working with lists of files is brittle even in the best of circumstances, and can usually be replaced with `find ... -exec`, or in your case, `find "$HOME/Desktop" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "\*.png" -delete` (with the additional benefit of not throwing an error in case `directory.png` exists. ;-) )

Answer (score 7):

The corresponding option in `zsh` is `CSH_NULL_GLOB` (documented in `man zshoptions`).b

```
 setopt CSH_NULL_GLOB
```

(As far as I can tell, the idea of a pattern disappearing rather than being treated literally comes from `csh`.)

Comment: Just tried this and it seems to be doing the job however now it errors out instead of just creating an empty array. 

Will see if there's anything that would fit my current script. If not I'll have to change my error handling :)

Comment: There is also `setopt NULL_GLOB`, which, AFAICT, differs from `CSH_NULL_GLOB` by not reporting an error even if all the globbing expressions produce no matches.  It is closer to the Bash `shopt -s nullglob` (and can even be spelled the same — `setopt nullglob` — because options to `setopt` are case-insensitive and ignore underscores).

Answer (score 4):

The more zsh-like approach is not to set this as a general option (as suggested in the answer given by chepner), but to decide on each pattern, whether or you want to have the *nullglob*  effect. For example,

```
for f in x*y*(N)
do
  echo $f
done
```

simply skips the loop if there are no files matching the pattern.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have fixed the issue for me:

    `for config_file in $HOME/.local/zsh/*.zsh
    do
        source $config_file;
    done`

results in `no matches found: ~/.local/zsh/*.zsh`

Comment: @IanEdington : You forgot the `(N)` in your code. Look at my example again.

Answer (score -2):

Just come to the realisation that the issue of `shopt` not being found was due to me auto-loading the file as a ZSH function.

The script worked perfectly when I ran it like so:

`bash ./tidy-desktop`

Previously I had been running it just with the command `tidy-desktop`

Instead I now have this in my `zsh_aliases`:

```sh
tidy-desktop="~/.zshfn/tidy-desktop"
```

Thanks to @Charles Duffy for helping me figure out what was going on there!

Comment: Don't use the `bash` command (or `sh` or `zsh` or...); that overrides the shebang, and unless you remember which scripts are written in which dialect, you'll probably run them with the wrong interpreter. Just make sure the script is executable (`chmod +x tidy-desktop`) and use `./tidy-desktop`. Or even better, put the script in a directory in your `PATH`, and use `tidy-desktop`; this way you can run it no matter what directory you happen to be in at the time.

Comment: Cheers Gordon. I've got an alias for it which just runs the script like so ```./tidy-desktop```. Though I might move it to a directory in my ```PATH``` as you suggest

I just thought I'd share what was causing the issue of the ```shopt: command not found```

Will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: Your "answer" is confusing. In your question, you were talking about using zsh, and now what you provide as an answer is using bash. I think you should first make up your mind which language you want to use, and then stick with it. Of course zsh doesn't know `setopt`, because this is a bash command. BTW, it's in general a bad idea to use a single file with definitions (be it aliases, functions or whatever) and use it for zsh **and** bash. The languages are so different that you will run into problems sooner or later.

Comment: Consider creating a directory like `$HOME/bin` to contain your scripts, and adding it to your `PATH`. That's more robust than aliases, which are only honored in interactive shells but can't be seen by other processes.